# Yii2 - How to grab id inside layout

Tags: php, yii2

I am needing to know the ID of the page being viewed from within my layout. Actually, it's rendered within my Layout.

```
site.com/controller/view/id
```

or

```
site.com/controller/id  <-- shorthand for the same above
```

I need to get that id number earlier, within my layout.

There is `$this->context->action->id` but that returns `view`. I don't see why it isn't possible for Yii to do this. If it doesn't exist, they should add it :)

I really don't want to chop the url, that's a chincy hack, and chincy hacks usually break later down the road for one reason or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get it from `$_GET['id']` or with `\Yii::$app->request->get('id');`.

If you have some logic depending on controller and item id being viewed consider place it into *widget*, this will make your layout more readable

**EDIT:**

*id* is just a parameter name, to get it in layout you can use two approaches noted above or if you want to use `context` you can get it like this `$this->context->actionParams['id']`

Comment: I know how to handle it from a controller. I need to access it from my layout file. You can use `$this->context->action->id` to get the action from anywhere, you should be able to do the same for id.. It's part of the route just like controller and action are.

Comment: Actually `id` is not a part of the route it is a parameter. see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#routes

Comment: Your absolutely right. I've been using pretty URLs for a while and didn't pay any attention to the id param.

Comment: I was well aware of `Yii::$app->request->get('id');`, though it seems to be my best option here. I tried actionParams, which worked only if the id was present, else it threw an error. So I resorted to the get() function because it has the isset check built in, to handle if it's empty. I was caught up thinking the id was handled like a controller and action, when it isn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your `yii\web\View.php` and add `$id` as a public property.[Or simply add `public $id;` in your `yii\web\View.php`]

Then in your view file,add

```
 $this->id='watever';
```

and get the same in your layout as

```
 <?php echo $this->id; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content is generated before the layout. Either way inside the controller before you call $this->render('view',['model' => $myModelVar, 'someotherparam' => $somevar']); 
You would set the \Yii::$app->params array. This will be accessable inside the layout.

e.g. in your controller.

```
public function actionView($id) { 
\Yii::$app->view->params['layoutvars'] = ['id' => $id];
return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

inside your layout file

```
$id = \Yii::$app->view->params['layoutvars']['id'];
```